# using jqueryDayField for a UTCTime

Tags: haskell, yesod

I'd like to convert the `Field (HandlerT site IO) Day` of the `jqueryDayField` into a `Field (HandlerT site IO) UTCTime` with `diffTime 0` since I am using mongodb as my database and Day just produces an integer value in the store and no actual date format.

i.e. I have something like this in my form code:

```
    <*> areq (dayToUTC $ (jqueryDayField def
        { jdsChangeYear = True -- give a year dropdown
        , jdsChangeMonth = True
        , jdsYearRange = "2000:"
        })) (fieldSettingsLabel MsgNewEntryDate) Nothing
```

where `dayToUTC` would do the conversion. Or should I use a different approach?

---

My solution so far is just havin a custom `jqueryUTCField :: (RenderMessage site FormMessage, YesodJquery site) => JqueryDaySettings -> Field (HandlerT site IO) UTCTime` function but I don't feel like this is necessarily the best solution.

Answer (score 3):

Something like the following should work:

```
dayToUTC <$> (areq (jqueryDayField def {...}) settings Nothing)
```